# An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, update-manager

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

Please report this bug against the **update-manager** package and include the following error message:
*'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'*

`sudo apt-get upgrade` brings me this.

```
renamon@Gibson{~}:sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libgl1-mesa-dev linux-headers-generic-lts-raring
  linux-image-generic-lts-raring mesa-common-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

`apt-get dist-upgrade -f` brings me this

```
root@Gibson:/home/renamon# apt-get dist-upgrade -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Failed
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring : Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-raring but it is not going to be installed
 libglapi-mesa-lts-raring:i386 : Conflicts: libglapi-mesa
                                 Conflicts: libglapi-mesa:i386
 libglu1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev or
                             libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-quantal but it is not going to be installed or
                             libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-raring but it is not going to be installed or
                             libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-saucy but it is not going to be installed or
                             libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-trusty but it is not installable or
                             libgl-dev
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
root@Gibson:/home/renamon#
```

Dont know much on this end of Linux, still a noob.

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part about the upgrade, just copy the packages that have been kept back, each line at a time, and append them to a `sudo apt-get install` statement and press enter.

In your case it will become:

> sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev linux-headers-generic-lts-raring linux-image-generic-lts-raring mesa-common-dev

This will take care of your 'these packages have been kept back error'.